# Sphinx adding entire module index to generated PDF

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I'm using Sphinx autodoc to create Python documentation, which is then hosted on ReadTheDocs [here](http://sensormotion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html). The PDF that is generated by ReadTheDocs only contains the TOC of my index page, which you can see [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/sensormotion/develop/sensormotion.pdf).

I want the PDF to also contain my entire module index and docs for every module/function: http://sensormotion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/source/sensormotion.html

So essentially I want my index TOC and full module pages both merged into the same PDF

What settings do I need to change in my `conf.py` to achieve this?

Currently I only have the default `latex_documents` options:

```
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'index.tex', project + ' Documentation',
     author, 'howto'),
]
```

I have tried adding another tuple to the list for the actual module/function references but nothing seems to be appended to the PDF:

```
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'index.tex', project + ' Documentation',
     author, 'howto'),
    ('sensormotion', 'sensormotion.tex', project + ' Documentation',
     author, 'howto'),
]
```

Comment: This is strange. I would expect the package to be documented for both HTML and PDF versions or for neither, but not for only HTML. Have you tried building PDF locally? I did notice a few warnings in the [build log](https://readthedocs.org/projects/sensormotion/builds/7070401/) by clicking each item, but nothing stands out. Your `conf.py` looks fine, too. Compare to the [default Sphinx `conf.py`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.6/config.html).

Comment: Trying to get rst2pdf working (windows) has been a pain so I havent been able to build a pdf locally. If you look at my docs on RTD you'll see that the module list isnt included in any TOCs, and the only way to access it is via a link through the Python Module Index - could that be the reason why its not included in the pdf?

Comment: That could be. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reference the rst files under `docs/source` from your `index.rst`. I think maybe the HTML builder searches for all rst files under docs, while the LaTeX builder renders the files you explicitly list under `latex_documents` (it creates one output PDF for each entry in this list).

Comment: so two things: 1) how do I reference the source files in `index.rst` without actually displaying them on the page? and 2) In my second example I added one of the source files to `latex_documents` but it doesnt seem to get added to the PDF

Comment: @Simon 1) you reference the file in your [`toctree`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#toctree-directive), and 2) each entry in the [`latex_documents`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config.html#confval-latex_documents) list creates a separate latex source file, so unless you combine these yourself afterwards, they create separate PDF files.